# How to scrape multiple pages in R

Tags: r, screen-scraping

I'm a beginning student in R, currently working on scraping the names and salaries of NBA players from: http://www.espn.com/nba/salaries/_/year/2019/page/1/seasontype/3

From this website I want to scrape al the 13 pages

I've found a function that lets me scrape the right amount of observations but instead of getting al the 13 pages. It repeats the first page 13 times and puts them al in 1 table. Anyone know how to fix this? It would help me out al lot

```r
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(readxl)
library(xml2)
library(readxl)
library(tibble)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)


salary_by_player = data.frame()

#link <- "http://www.espn.com/nba/salaries/_/year/2019/page/1/seasontype/3"
for(page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 13, by = 1)){
  link = paste("http://www.espn.com/nba/salaries/_/year/2019/page/", page_result, "/seasontype/3")
  page = read_html(link)
  
  name = page %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_text()
  salary = page %>% html_nodes(".oddrow td:nth-child(4) , .evenrow td:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
  salary_by_player = rbind(salary_by_player, data.frame(name, salary, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) 
  
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `paste()` by default uses spaces to join the strings. You can fix this by specifying the `sep` parameter like so:

```
link = paste("http://www.espn.com/nba/salaries/_/year/2019/page/", page_result, "/seasontype/3", sep='')
```

Or fully written out like this:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)

salary_by_player = data.frame()

for(page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 13, by = 1)){
  link = paste("http://www.espn.com/nba/salaries/_/year/2019/page/", page_result, "/seasontype/3", sep='')
  page = read_html(link)
  
  name = page %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_text()
  salary = page %>% html_nodes(".oddrow td:nth-child(4) , .evenrow td:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
  salary_by_player = rbind(salary_by_player, data.frame(name, salary, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) 
  
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))
}
```